# Define &nbsp; in a variable in PHP? <space1> = &nbsp <space2> = &nbsp;&nbsp; etc

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I've got a custom WP plugin that creates a shortcode.

For example my plugin works like this:

```
[text]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello all, thank you![/text]
```

I need to add these for various reasons.

```
Is there a way I can define &nbsp; so that I can just write:

[text]<space3>Hello all, thank you![/text] or something similar?

i.e. <space3> = &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just type `$space3 = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp";` and then `echo "{$space3}Hello all, thank you";`

Comment: This is a short code for front end so would rather have no echo etc. just simple variable name. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: As you're defining a php variable, you need to somehow echo it out. How about `<?=$space3?>Hello all, thank you!` at least it doesn't say echo ;)